# when i use intersection types in tsx , it's broken. how to resolve

Tags: reactjs, typescript

when i use intersection types in tsx , it's broken!

example from official documents

```
function extend<T, U>(first: T, second: U): T & U {
    let result = <T & U>{};
    for (let id in first) {
        (<any>result)[id] = (<any>first)[id];
    }
    for (let id in second) {
        if (!result.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            (<any>result)[id] = (<any>second)[id];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
error: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not about intersection types, but about the syntax used to perform a *type assertion*. When using the `.tsx` extension, you cannot use angle brackets for type assertions because angle brackets are interpreted as JSX.

Instead of this:

```
let result = <T & U>{};
```

do this:

```
let result = {} as T & U;
```

As a side note: you could skip the assertions whatsoever and implement your function as:

```
function extend<T, U>(first: T, second: U): T & U {
  return Object.assign({}, first, second);
}
```